# unable to create a custom camera inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-camera2

Is it possible to create a custom camera inside a fragment(not call the android default camera projecting the results onto a "Preview" surface or SurfaceView) and do i need to assign another thread for it?? I am try to create an application which needs an custom camera in a part of my UI

Comment: for your first question yes you can create custom camera inside fragment

Comment: If i create a custom camera in a fragment will it require its own thread and is there any available project like this for my reference??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about a background thread for **camera2** API, it is assigned by default (you still can provide custom Handler, if you wish).

Generally, there is no difference whether you open your camera with or without Fragment. Still, you must make sure that the camera is released in `Activity.onPause()`. Luckily, for your convenience, this is automatically propagated to your fragment.